# how to read multiple files from a file in Apache Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have one file named "filelist.txt" and the content of this file is a list files which I want to read into my pig script. For example, it can be organized as:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
...
filen.txt
```

some of the solutions are trying to use regular expression, however there is no particular format in the filenames, the only thing we can do is to read the filenames from the filelist.txt

in each of the file is the actual data I want to read. For example, in file1, we can have:

```
value1
value2
value3
```

So how should I be able to read all these files values in my pig scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use pig load func and overwrite  setlocation

```
 @Override
    public void setLocation(String location, Job job) throws IOException {
        //Read location where you have all the input file names and convert that into a comma seperated string.
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, [commaseperated list]);
    }
```

Where location will be comma seperated list of your files.

Comment: I didn't get it. It seems that you already know the format of file. But what I want is to read the files whose filenames are in another filelist. How should I do that?

Comment: Yes, i misread earlier version. I think the above one looks good. Not sure if it solves issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to currently do this in pure pig.  The best you can do in pure pig is use their builtin globbing which you can find information about [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)).  It is fairly flexible, but doesn't sound like it will be enough for your purposes.

The other solution I can think of, if you can get that file in your local environment, is to use some sort of [wrapper (I would recommend python)](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/cont.html#embed-python).  In that script you can read the file and generate a pig script to read those lines.  Here is how that logic would work:

```
def addLoads(filesToRead, schema, delim='\\t'):

    newLines = []
    with open(filesToRead, 'r') as infile:

        for n, f in enumerate(infile):
            newLines.append("input{} = LOAD '{}' USING PigStorage('{}') AS {};".format(n, f, delim, schema))

    to_union = [ 'input{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(newLines)+1) ]

    newLines.append('loaded_lines = UNION {} ;'.format(', '.join(to_union)))

    return '\n'.join(newLines)
```

Append the this to the beginning of the pig script you load from disk, and make sure that the rest of the script uses `loaded_lines` as the start.